# How to add a login password when start/launching Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

When I installed Ubuntu, I did not add a password since I am using only of movies and music.
Now I am using it for other purpose as well.

So when I launch Ubuntu, it does not ask login password.

I want to add a password. I tried system>preference>about me and system>passwords and encryption keys but none of them ask me password when I start Ubuntu.

Could anyone tell me how to add a password to login?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Huh, is it even possible to **not** set a password? You will always need a password when you perform administrative tasks, like software updates or changing network settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The place you want is:

> System -> Administration -> Login Screen

[image]

Make sure it is set to "Show the screen for choosing who will log in" and then save it and reboot.

When the computer starts up you should be presented with a list of users on the system (if *Show list of users* was checked) or a box to enter your login name.  You will then need to enter your password (the one you use for administrative tasks) to get any further.

If you managed to create your user account without a password (not sure if this is actually possible), then adding a password to your account can be done number of ways.

The simplest way is just to open a Terminal window (Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal) and typing `passwd` at the prompt.  If you already have a password set it will ask for that before allowing you to change your password.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for this:

`System->Administration->Users and Groups`.  It should be pretty easy to find from there.